# Porque el range slider se ve diferente en la computadora y en el celular

Tags: html, app, programación-móvil, framework7

[Enlace a la aplicacion de prueba](http://judasniper.neocities.org/advance/index.html)

Tengo una app mobile que estoy haciendo con framewrok7 pero el range slider que utilizo se ve diferente en la version de pc que la version mobile.

Basicamente es el circulo o elemento que determina la posicion del slider lo que no se ve.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<div class="item-input">
              <div class="range-slider">
                <h2  id='Peso1' >Peso:</h2>  
                <h2  id='Peso1' >Aqui debe ir el peso * power:</h2>  
                  <input type="range" oninput="mouseDown(); "  min="3.5" max="50" value="12.5" step ="0.50" >
                </div>
          </div>
```